# JQuery AJAX method calls "error" function instead of "success" function on JSONP request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I cant access the asp.net web API which is build on .net framework 4.0 from jQuery AJAX call.

WebAPI returns following JSON result

```
["Value1", "Value2"]
```

WebClient implements following jQuery code to access the WebAPI

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'http://localhost:62915/api/values',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       dataType: "jsonp",
       success: function (data) {           
          alert('success');               
          console.log(data);
       },
       error: function (reason) {
           alert('fail');
           console.log(reason);
       }
});
```

I dont get any error message on chrome network tab and i can see the expected JSON result on top of it.

But, The problem is instead of calling the "success" method it calls "error" method.
What is wrong in my jQuery code?

Thanks in Advance.
--SJ

Comment: What is errorCode? have you checked the url http://localhost:62915/api/values on the address bar in the browser?

Comment: The browser returns expected JSON result but i can't access that values from JQuery Call

Comment: Why jsonp? is it cross domains? you should specify callback in the url

Comment: Yes, Its a cross domain function call. While logging result object, i get result like this **Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}**

Comment: The above jQuery method get the JSON result properly but instead of calling *success* method it fallback to *error* method.

Comment: it's in you local, add 'crossDomain:true' to force cross domain

Comment: Its not working fine after adding *crossDomain:true* (Still I'm facing the same issue)

Comment: Please paste details of error example in Chrome network tab, it's easier to diagnose.

Comment: @FredHO, I didn't get any error in chrome network tab. as well as i can see the expected JSON result under network tab. But the above mentioned jQuery calls *error* method instead of *success* method.

Comment: try fetching the `reason.responseText` and see what it says

Comment: @AminJafari, reason.responseText is *undefined*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue it canbe is your API does not support JSONP yet. You can make it work in some steps.

- Install a package from nuget WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp
- Call an extension method AddJsonpFormatter on your HttpConfiguration instance

It should work then.

[image]

More details on jsonp :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp